# Курсор unity 3d

Tags: c#, курсор

Всем доброго времени суток, дорогие друзья! Я сделал паузу для игры, но курсор находится по середине и им нельзя двигать, но его можно увидеть. Что делать?
Скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;

    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
                Cursor.visible = true;
            } else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Resume ()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
    void Pause ()

    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }

    public void LoadMenu()

    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("Quitting game...");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Если что могу скинуть скрипт камеры который блокирует курсор

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите? Показать курсор когда игра на паузе или спрятать? Потому что сейчас вы ничего не делаете с курсором при постановке на паузу.

Comment: Я хочу чтобы через паузу можно было выйти в меню поэтому показать

Comment: `Cursor.visible = true;` перенесите в соседний блок, там где `Pause()`.

Comment: Именно перенести не скопировать?

Comment: Сначала пробовать, потом спрашивать :)

Comment: Перенёс, также курсор на одном месте в середине

Comment: Там где у вас блокиррвка в камере добавьте проверку. Если курсора нет, двигать камеру, если есть - ничего не делать.

Comment: Можешь помочь с её написанием?

Comment: Легко `if (!Cursor.visible) { выполнять блокировку курсора; }`

Comment: Я уже исправил, но всё равно спасибо!)